# "System.ListException: Row with duplicate Name at index: 47" error from list custom setting getall()

Tags: apex, customsetting

The following exception started occurring when retrieving all the values from a list custom setting:

> System.ListException: Row with duplicate Name at index: 47

The code in question for the error line was:

```
for(ListCustomSetting__c f : ListCustomSetting__c.getall().values()) {
    //..
}
```

The exception could be replicated with the following anonymous Apex:

```
System.debug(ListCustomSetting__c.getall());
```

Oddly, this code had been deployed as part of a managed package for at least 2 years (according to the last touch in source control).

**Why has this only failed now and what caused it to fail?**

Answer (score 4):

Somehow Custom Setting records with duplicate names have been created.
[image: Duplicate Custom Setting Names].

If you attempt to edit either of those records it gets blocked due to the Name conflict.

As mentioned in the question, when they do exist attempts to call `ListCustomSetting__c.getall()` produce the ListException for duplicate name at index.

That explains why the problem is occurring, but not how Salesforce got into that state. I suspect two transactions were populating the custom list setting around the same time, but it is difficult to replicate. If you take the last character in the Id's you get two sets between the duplicates (n,o,p,q,r,s) and (t,u,v,w,x,y).

Deleting the duplicates resolved the problem.

Comment: I've had a similar situation occur once. Never explained, but it does happen.

Comment: @sfdcfox I think it was just a freak timing thing that somehow created the duplicates. Either a race between two transactions or some retry mechanism that made the duplicates. I mostly posted this Q&A as it hadn't been addressed on SFSE yet.

Comment: @sfdcfox This is actually reproducible. Added it in answer

Answer (score 3):

When **separate** transactions insert the custom setting with same name, its is **not** able to validate the duplication.

But in same transaction, it is able to validate.

**PROOF:**

I am able to create even 3 duplicate records.

[image]

I tested this in LWC.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-input label="Enter"></lightning-input>
    <lightning-button label="Create" onclick={double}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import createPoc from '@salesforce/apex/poc.createPoc';

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {
    insertPoc() {
        createPoc({ name: this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').value })
            .then(() => console.log('SUCCESS'))
            .catch((err) => console.error('ERROR => ', err));
    }
    double() {
        this.insertPoc();
        this.insertPoc();
        this.insertPoc();
    }
}
```

APEX:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String createPoc(String name){
    POC__c pp = new POC__c(Name=name);
    insert pp;
    return 'SUCCESS';
}
```

**This is a serious bug.**

Comment: Thanks for the repo. I'll take it through to Salesforce support to see if we can get a known issue created and/or a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this issue in Test Context. One has to insert one in TestSetup and other in unitTest. It allows inserting but when you try to do getAll it breaks with

`System.ListException: Row with duplicate Name at index: 1`

Minimum Viable Code to reproduce:

```
@IsTest
public class ListCSTest {

     @TestSetup
    private static void setupData(){
        Insert new ListCS__C(Name='Pikachu');
    }

    private static testmethod void unitTest(){
         Insert new ListCS__C(Name='Pikachu');

         System.assertEquals(1, ListCS__C.getAll().size());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, this can also happen with Managed Packages.  If I deploy a Custom Metadata record and then the Customer creates a second record of that same type, they will be allowed to save it (probably because it's a different Namespace).

We had this issue with package upgrades.  Originally, we provided the mdt structure and customers had to add the record manually.  When we later started deploying mdt records *with* our package, those customers that had already added one manually, had issues (until they deleted the second record).